# what is the function of prefix "a" of parameter in java?

Tags: java

for example,sometimes I see function like this:

```
public void changeColor(Color aColor){
}
```

what is the function or meaning of "a" in parameter "aColor"?

Comment: It looks like it means "a color" as in "a color to change to"

Comment: None, it's just part of the name of the variable.

Comment: It seems like a naming convention, not anything functional.

Comment: It's a means by which you can use the variable within your code, if it doesn't have a name, then how can you address it, "Hay, you, color, yeah, you over there!"?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think the question is about the "a" in "aColor", not about "aColor" itself.

Comment: @user1803551 It's still just a means to address a variable :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer It's part of the means :P

Comment: It's the Hungarian notation and you should not use it.

Comment: The programmer thinks it reads better, that's all. Most people would simply use `color`.

Comment: `a` is one of two forms (along with `an`) of the [indefinite article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_article). It is used to signify that the following noun is not a specific one and that its identity is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

That is just what they named the variable. You may also see "m" in a lot of other people's code, especially if you look through the Java source code. Example mColor, mOnTouchListener, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Functions take arguments. In Java these arguments must be declared as a type(in this case a "Color" object) and named. The name of the argument doesn't matter. Imagine it as creating a new Color variable as such.

```
Color aColor;
```

and setting the variables value to whatever Color object you pass the function when you call it.

Now you have a Color named aColor that has a value that you set. There is nothing special about the name aColor, its just a name.